# How to set a file path or a symlink path for rocketchat(meteor) app running in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ubuntu-14.04, rocket.chat

I am new to node.js, meteor. I am working with analyzing an app (Rocket Chat) which was build using meteor. I am trying to setup rocket chat app demo with localhost.

So I just download app source code from "https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat" and run with meteor. It shows errors " Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory" and "Builder can not write without either data or a file path or a symlink path".

I have searched for solution for this issues, I got some reference, as I need to set some "Environment variable" for app. But not clear about what value needs to set in environment variable.Hereby I attached the screenshot of error, I have received. http://postimg.org/image/4dda23c59/

How can I set environment variable, How to fix those issues? Anyone can help me!
Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: It looks like your instance is running short on memory. If you need to use some environment variables, one way of doing it is defining them right before the `meteor` command. Like this: `ROOT_URL=http://localhost:2000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor --port 2000`